# No Class files being generated from Adding a Reference to Web Service

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I'm integrated our website with a 3rd party site and using their web service to authenticate. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with Visual Basic and I'm able to use the URL they gave me to add a web reference using:

```
website -> add web reference -> URL -> Go -> add reference
```

However, after I do this there aren't any class files generated in my file structure to reference?

The files generated are:

- .discomap

  - .disco
  - .wsdl
  - .xsd
  - .wsdl
  - .xsd
  - .xsd

I don't know if it is relevant, but the webservice was made using visual studio 2008.

Every tutorial I have read online has said that class files should be generated after the reference is successfully added. Am I just reading things wrong or is something else amuck?

Thanks!

Comment: Look in the  Output window. Any errors? Is this a web site "project"?

Comment: No errors are generated and it is a web site, not a project. Do I need to run a command from the command line to generate the files maybe?

Comment: Web sites are weird. The code may be generated at runtime.

Comment: So... I should reference the class as if it was generated...?

Comment: I have no clue. That's why I don't use web site "projects".  Note how I guessed you were using web sites - just because something weird was happening that was different from the tutorials. That's because the tutorials are for real projects.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to generate the class file from the Visual Studio command line. The same link that I used to Add Web Reference was the link needed for the command line text.

This generated two files, a class file and an output.config file. I had to combine the output.config file with my web.config file and then the webservice was called correctly.